# not able to get angular 2 scope inside call back functions

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to update a array object inside a call back function ,i used the following lines but the values are set in the scope of call back loop not as angular variable so my view is not updated.(deviceval) value is changed if i print it inside the callback but outside the value is still the old one.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  hideTable: boolean = true;
  public  deviceVal:any;
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deviceVal = deviceData;
    console.log(this.deviceVal);
    var container = $('.map-canvas');
    var options = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.676258, -99.683199),
     zoom: 4,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    gmap = new google.maps.Map(container[0], options);
    this.drawChart(deviceData);
    this.plotMarkers();
  }

  plotMarkers(){
    $.each(deviceData, function(key, val) {
      var controller=this;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(val.lat), parseInt(val.lon)),
        map: gmap,
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        this.deviceVal = val;
      });
      markerCache.push(marker);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should be using `$scope.$apply()` wherever you are using a non angular callback to tell angular to run a change detection cycle.

Comment: I don't think thats the only issue, your pointer is also incorrect. You are assigning the `this` reference (of the class) inside the callback. I think you meant to put that above the callback so it points to the correct ```this.deviceVal```

Comment: @Abdel there is no $scope in Angular 2

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
$.each(deviceData, function(key, val) {
  var controller=this;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(val.lat), parseInt(val.lon)),
    map: gmap,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    this.deviceVal = val;
  });
  markerCache.push(marker);
})
```

when you use function() as a callback function, the 'this' value is changed. You better read here about this.

You can fix this using arrow functions:

```
plotMarkers(){
    $.each(deviceData, (key, val) => {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(val.lat), parseInt(val.lon)),
        map: gmap,
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
        this.deviceVal = val;
      });
    })
  }
```

But you have a lot of other problems, like: you don't need to use jQuery (to be honest, you should avoid jQuery in an ng2 app), the 'gmap' variable is not defined (you can set it as an property of the class, as you have done with 'deviceVal' for example), 'markerCache' was not defined too, there is no drawChart method, 'deviceData' is not defined inside plotMarkers().

Comment: Correct, this will ensure his pointer is referencing the thing he wants to reference. Which is the class.

Comment: hi christian i have declared gmap,markercache globally before the export class and i have just uploaded the problematic part of my code.where the drawchart is not mentioned

Comment: i had changed function using arrow functions still the view is not refreshed

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by declaring a global variable before export component like

```
var controller;
```

and initialized it in ngoninit(),

```
controller = this;
```

and passed the controller to addlistener,

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
                           controller.deviceVal=[];
                            controller.deviceVal.push(val);
                          //console.log(controller.deviceVal+"end....................................")
                          });
```